# Select Last Value Right To Left from 3 Columns

Tags: sql

I have a table containing the following records:

```
Rec | Col1  | Col2  | Col3  |
--  | ----  | ----  | ----  |
1   | 1234  |       |       |
2   | 1235  | 2346  | 3456  |
3   | 1236  | 2347  |       |
4   | 1237  | 2348  | 3458  |
5   | 1238  |       |       |
6   | 1239  | 2349  |       |
```

I would like to capture in a single column, the rightmost value in each row for columns 1, 2 and 3, like:

```
Rec | RgtV  |
--  | ----  |
1   | 1234  |
2   | 3456  |
3   | 2347  |
4   | 3458  |
5   | 1238  |
6   | 2349  |
```

Can anyone help me with the SQL query that I would use to extract such a column?

Regards,

Wayne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select rec, coalesce(col3, col2, col1) as RgtV
from t;
```

EDIT:

If the values are empty strings, you can revise this to:

```
select rec,
       coalesce(nullif(col3, ''), nullif(col2, ''), nullif(col1, '')) as RgtV
from t;
```

Comment: As simple as it gets. +1

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. However, I guess my sample data above wasn't very well thought out. I didn't realize coalesce was the solution. However, when I tried that, I got unexpected results, in that only column 3 (Col3) values were returned in my resulting "RgtV" column.? Could that be due to my actual Table containing many records with null values in all 3 columns?

Comment: @WayneWalker . .  . That would occur if the values were NOT `NULL`.  For instance, the values look like numbers.  But if they were strings, then they might be the empty string (`''`) rather than `NULL`.

Comment: Oh, then that would explain it. I will check that out, as I think you're right that my columns are configured as varchar and I can change them to numeric. Will provide feedback if that works, in case it helps others who experience the same issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks so much for your help with this!!! You second query that caters for empty strings did the trick for me. It works perfectly. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out on this one. Always glad to learn something new.